# SetMargin in RPGLE on iSeries (HSSF Scott Klement Java)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle, hssf

i use the HSSF Excel-Tool from Scott Klement on iSeries.

I try to setup the Margins on my Excelfile to Print my Excel with smaller margins.
But the margin methods aren't in the Scott Klement HSSF as an RPGLE Prototype.

My Question:
How can i use the setMargin Method in RPGLE?
How do I have to write the prototype in HSSF to use it on my RPGLE-Code?

Here the Java-Code that i need for my RPG:

```
    sheet.setMargin ( Sheet.LeftMargin, 0.25 );
    sheet.setMargin ( Sheet.RightMargin, 0.25 );
    sheet.setMargin ( Sheet.TopMargin, 0.25 );
    sheet.setMargin ( Sheet.BottomMargin, 0.5 );
```

Here for example the running RPG Code for setting the page in Landscape

```
PrintOptions = SSSheet_getPrintSetup(sheet);   
SSPrintSetup_setLandscape(PrintOptions: *ON);
```

Prototype in HSSF:

```
D SSSheet_getPrintSetup...                                        
D                 PR                  like(SSPrintSetup)          
D                                     extproc(*JAVA               
D                                     : SHEET_CLASS               
D                                     : 'getPrintSetup')          

D SSPrintSetup_setLandscape...                                       
D                 PR                  extproc(*JAVA                  
D                                     : PRINTSETUP_CLASS             
D                                     : 'setLandscape')              
D   setting                      1N   value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to look at the Java interface

```
public void setMargin(short margin,
                      double size)
```

And build the RPG prototype, something like so: (My Java is a bit rusty)

```
dcl-c LEFT_MARGIN   const(0);
dcl-c RIGHT_MARGIN  const(1);
dcl-c TOP_MARGIN    const(2);
dcl-c BOTTOM_MARGIN const(3);

dcl-pr SSSheet_setMargin extproc(*JAVA: SHEET_CLASS: 'setMargin');
  margin like(jshort) value;
  size   like(jdouble) value;
end-pr;
```

Now you can call it

```
SSSheet_setMargin(LEFT_MARGIN:0.25);
```

Comment: I always just added additional methods to the HSSF copy book using existing methods as a template. It isn't really hard. The problems will be if you try to upgrade POI. It is up around version 4 now, and at version 3.15 or so, they broke Scott's header files by shifting to enums vs integers for things like margin type codes.